# Kivy; How to id a KV lang width in python code?

Tags: python, events, kivy, kivy-language

When a window-level event (such as a mouse click or a drag-n-drop) occurs in a Kivy application, it gets passed to the entire widget tree.  I have multiple widgets of the same class spread across my UI, and need to know which the event occured over.  Although I can filter using `self.collide()`, once I've done that I need to know WHICH widget it is - i.e. is it the top widget in my UI, or the bottom, or what.

I had intended to do this by giving unique names to the "id" value in the kv file for each relevant widget, then run cases in my code based on that.  But I was disappointed to [find out](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids) that "...note that the id will not be available in the widget instance..."

so what's the best practice for giving each widget a unique ID in the kv lang file that can be reference in code?  Certainly I could use object properties, but that seems like overkill.  Is there some simpler method?

Comment: What that mean is that the widget can't access its `id` by using the `self.id` attribute. ..But the `root` layout will know which widget has which `id`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the widgets an identifying attribute or property. If you wanted a string ID, use a StringProperty. It isn't really clear to me that this app structure is the best way to do solve your problem, but it will work fine.